# How can I get the entity attributes metadata list?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Dynamics 365 v8.2.2.

Why `attributesMetadata` is `null`? How can I get the entity attributes metadata list?

```
{
    var req = new RetrieveEntityRequest {
        LogicalName = "opportunity",
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,
    };

    var resp = srv.Execute(req) as RetrieveEntityResponse;
    var entityMetadata = resp.EntityMetadata;
    var attributesMetadata = entityMetadata.Attributes; // null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [EntityFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entityfilters?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) in request like:

```
EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All
```

Or

```
EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes
```

The complete snippet as follows:

```
RetrieveEntityRequest retrieveEntityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
    LogicalName = "opportunity"
};
RetrieveEntityResponse retrieveOpptyEntityResponse(RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(retrieveEntityRequest);
EntityMetadata opptyEntity = retrieveOpptyEntityResponse.EntityMetadata;
```

By default, `EntityFilters.Default` only entity information will be retrieved, that’s why you have empty attribute list.

[Read more](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-365-get-entity-metadata-using-c/)